# Querying SQL database through R, and returning a specific list

Tags: sql, r, jdbc

I must query and SQL database through R, and am having difficulty getting it to return what I need. Basically, the database has columns "timeStamp", "line", "aggregate", "name", "location" and "topic". Here is my attempt to get all the UNIQUE topics and their associated column values between a time range:

```
con <- openConn()
query <- "SELECT DISTINCT topic, line, aggregate, name, location FROM doc.database
WHERE \"timeStamp"\ BETWEEN '2023-06-01 00:00:00' AND ' 2023-10-30 10:00:00'
GROUP BY topic"
topicsdf <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

However, this returns an error:

Error in dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...) :
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
JDBC ERROR: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
Statement:
SELECT DISTINCT topic,line, aggregate, name, location
FROM doc.database
WHERE "timeStamp" BETWEEN '2023-06-01 00:00:00' AND ' 2023-10-30 10:00:00'

Help on this is greatly appreciated, as I am unfamiliar with this type of query

Comment: Your query is invalid.  Please add sample data, before and after, so that someone may provide a valid query.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to aggregate functions.

Comment: And combing GROUP BY with SELECT DISTINCT is very rarely needed.

Comment: It's difficult to give help without data.  One thought, I tend to use the `dbplyr` package for constructing SQL queries, as it's usually easier to see where things are not working and it can then generate the SQL query

Comment: why do I have to add sample data? It is a simple database, with the columns i specified. the only question is how to properly execute the JDBC query of SQL through R, resulting in a simple dataframe where there is a row for every DISTINCT topic in the time range, with the associated values from the other columns I include

Comment: Let's say a given topic has 2 rows.  What is your logic for _which_ single record should be returned from those 2 rows?

Comment: Don't expect to get any help if no-one understand what the problem is. A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Make it easy to help you!

Comment: Also, please tag your question with your actual SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.).

Comment: I would love to provide a specific example but I can't even get the query to run. @TimBiegeleisen you make an excellent point, and this is the reason I am trying to run this query. I want to identify wherever that issue is occuring, so I can address how to choose which row. perhaps i can select all distinct combinations of column values per topic?

Comment: [1/2] ambergris, some other thoughts, both meta to the question and about SQL use in general: (1) Your code is currently a parsing error, sometimes caused by re-typing your code in the question instead of pasting in code you've actually tried. This can be difficult/frustrating since we don't always know if your problem is really represented by the code we see.

Comment: [2/2] ... (2) If not already, I strongly urge the use of [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries) (for several reasons). What you have here (literals) is fine and I often use string-literals when looking interactively, but this often leads to the use of `paste` or `sprintf` which should be avoided in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is doing a `GROUP BY` on the topic, which is asking your SQL database to return one record per value of topic.  However, the query also selects other columns, not inside aggregate functions.  It is therefore not clear *which* values of `line`, `aggregate`, `name`, or `location` should be returned, hence this query generates an error on your database.

You clarified your requirement in the comments:

> perhaps i can select all distinct combinations of column values per topic?

In this case, you can try simply dropping the `GROUP BY` clause and doing a distinct select:

```r
con <- openConn()
query <- "SELECT DISTINCT topic, line, aggregate, name, location
          FROM doc.database
          WHERE \"timeStamp\" BETWEEN '2023-06-01 00:00:00' AND ' 2023-10-30 10:00:00'"
topicsdf <- dbGetQuery(con, query)
```